# Explain the difference between these two questions, because their answers are different.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Q1- What is the total number of ways of selecting at least one object from $2$ sets of $12$ different objects, each set contains $6$ objects?

The answer is $4095$.

> Q2- What is the total number of ways of selecting at least one object from $2$ different sets, each set containing $6$ identical objects?

The answer is $48$.

Comment: The questions are different.  Perhaps you could explain why you thought the answers would be the same.

Comment: No I didn't thought the answer would be same. Actually I couldn't find out difference in solving them.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the first question the objects in a set are different, so it matters not only how many you take, but which ones. In the second question the objects in each set are the same, so all that matters is how many you take.

Comment: Oh I got it now. Can you please explain how we got 48 as the answer of question 2.

Comment: @Aayushmethi You have $7$ options for each set ($0$ to $6$ objects selected) with $1$ invalid selection $(0+0)$ This gives $7\times7-1=48$

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.